# Projectile launched from an elevation onto a slope, why is the impact velocity in the Y-direction up (positive) rather than down (negative)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, projectile

To solve for the impact velocity of the skier in the $y$-direction for part **b)** of the following problem, is it possible to use the formula:
$$v_{fy}^2 = v_{iy}^2 + 2aΔd_y$$

Once I have solved for the displacement and initial velocity in the $y$-direction. I declared down to be negative, and I would expect to have a negative (down) final velocity in the $y$-direction, yet when multiplying the $y$-direction displacement, which is negative, by the vertical acceleration which is due to gravity and therefore down/negative, I get a positive velocity, which would represent the up direction. I'm not sure why/how this is happening. Any clarificaiton/help would be much appreciated.

> A terrain park skier jumps off a $3.00 \ \rm [m]$ roller at $θ_i$ above the horizontal to a peak height of $5.50\ \rm [ m]$, travels a horizontal distance of $1.80\ \rm [m]$ and lands on the $30°$ slope of the next roller. The horizontal distance from the jumping off point to the peak height of the jump is $0.95\ \rm [m]$.
> a) What was the skier’s initial velocity and launch angle in order to follow this trajectory?
> b) At what distance up the slope of the second roller does the skier land and at what velocity?

Comment: +1 for reformulating your question in suitable manner for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation $$v_f^2 = v_0^2 + 2a\Delta d$$

has the $v_f$ term squared. This implies that both $v_f=v$ and $v_f=-v$ satisfy the equation. When you take the square root, you get $$v_f = \pm \sqrt{v_0^2 + 2a\Delta d}$$

Because the trajectory is a perfect parabola, both positive and negative solutions may be valid (I say *may be* because one solution might end up occurring for a negative value of time, rendering it non valid).

The bottom line is that it's **up to you** to decide which velocity (positive or negative) to keep. Since you know the skier is falling down, and you declared downwards as negative, you keep the negative solution.

Comment: Thanks so much! that clarifies it really well!